# Stacklayout navigate using Item Id instead of currentIndex = #num

Tags: qt, qml, stacklayout

I am using `StackLayout` with many windows, instead of using the `currentIndex = 0` for example I want to use the id for the Item itself. This way I will not need to care which order are the Items implemented in within the `StackLayout`, and the code will be easier to read.

I didn't happen to find how to do so or if it's actually possible. Any ideas?

Sample code:

main.qml

```
StackLayout {
    id: mainStack
    width: parent.width - tabbar.width
    x: tabbar.width

    PageOne {id: pageOne}

    PageTwo {id: pageTwo}

    PageThree {id: pageThree}
}

Button {
    text: "Go to"
    onClicked: {
        mainStack.currentIndex = 0  // how its done
        mainStack.currentIndex = pageOne  //what I want: using Item Id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method that does the search on the children of the StackLayout and if it finds it then change the currentIndex to the associated index:

```
StackLayout {
    id: mainStack
    width: parent.width - tabbar.width
    x: tabbar.width

    function changeTo(item){
        for(var i in this.children){
            if(this.children[i] === item){
                this.currentIndex = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    PageOne {id: pageOne}

    PageTwo {id: pageTwo}

    PageThree {id: pageThree}
}

Button {
    text: "Go to"
    onClicked: {
        mainStack.changeTo(pageOne)
    }
}
```

Comment: great workaround, it works fine. This will enhance the code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt 5.15 you can use the attached property of the StackLayout to access index of a page.

Like so :

```cpp
StackLayout {
     Item { id: pageOne }
     Item { id: pageTwo }
     Item { id: pageThree }
}

Button {
    text: "Go to"
    onClicked: {
        mainStack.currentIndex = pageOne.StackLayout.index
    }
}
```